# The instance of entity type cannot be tracked even with AsNoTracking

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, linq

I receive an error in test environment, but not on the prod environment even as no tracking has already been placed.

> Error "GetUserAsync: System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'UserEntity' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

Code:

```
internal async Task<UserEntity> GetUserAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var result = await _userDataQuery.GetLatestUser(cancellationToken);
}
```

I already added `AsNoTracking`:

```
public async Task<UserEntity> GetLatestUser(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var result = await this.Entities
                           .OrderByDescending(m => m.Id)
                           .AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    await Context.Entry(result).ReloadAsync();

    return result;
}
```

Not sure if this help but the I also notice the pg_sequences on postgreSQL between the two environments are different for User Table and both of them only have 1 record in the table

Test Environment:

```
last_value = 2
```

Prod Environment:

```
last_value = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that within the lifetime scope of the `DbContext` (Context) that entity has already been loaded and is being tracked. This could be directly via a different method call, or indirectly by being eager or lazy loaded as part of another entity load. `Reload` will attempt to track the entity which will result in an error where another matching instance is already tracked.

From what I can make of what you are trying to do, you probably don't want to use `AsNoTracking()` since you cannot guarantee that the entity hasn't already been tracked. Load it as-per normal.

```
var result = await this.Entities
                       .OrderByDescending(m => m.Id)
                       .FirstAsync();
await Context.Entry(result).ReloadAsync();
```

Whenever you use an `*OrDefault()` flavour, you *must* handle the fact that there may be no items in the set. If you expect at least one, use `First`.

The downside here is that Reload will be called even when the desired item is already freshly loaded from the DB. Since we cannot assume the desired item is or isn't already tracked, about the best option would probably be:

```
var id = this.Entities
             .OrderByDescending(m => m.Id)
             .Select(x => x.Id)
             .FirstAsync();

var result = this.Entities.Local
                       .Where(m => m.Id == id)
                       .SingleOrDefault();
if (result != null)
    await Context.Entry(result).ReloadAsync();
else
    result = this.Entities
        .Where(m => m.Id == id)
        .Single();
```

This code looks for a particular item in the local tracking cache, if found it will reload it, otherwise it will load the current item from the DB.

This approach (minus selecting the ID from the DB) would apply in any other situations where you know ahead of time what specific entity you want rather than relying on something like `FirstOrDefault` and want to ensure any already tracked entity is available and refresh it.

Comment: removing AsNoTracking worked, this make sense thank you.!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Removing AsNoTracking helps but unclear why. The point of `ReloadAsync()` is to reload actual data from Db which can be changed outside of the code, not just ensuring its presence in the local cache. The point of `.AsNoTracking()` is to have read-only entity with faster access. `OrDefault()` point is not related to the problem at all. I'm afraid the sample code and discussion above a bit irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Removing AsNoTracking works because if the DbContext is already tracking that reference it will give you that tracked reference, AsNotracking will not only not add a loaded entity into the cache, it bypasses the local cache entirely, not returning any entity that happens to be in the cache. This creates the problem that if you then want to attach that entity, the DbContext is already tracking that original reference.  The comment about the misuse of "OrDefault" is advice to help avoid NullReferenceExceptions or inconsistent results due to assumptions.

Comment: I think, it's just misleading error text. The actual problem is `ReloadAsync()` wants to reload entity into _Unchanged_ state while `AsNoTracking()` skips the state completely, so nothing to change. Resolution is to use the same query again with `AsNoTracking()` enabled, instead of `ReloadAsync()`, as it always loads fresh data from Db.

Comment: To do so it would attempt to re-associate that detached object reference with the DbContext which is the source of the error. The DbContext is already tracking an instance with that ID. I was actually a bit surprised that AsNoTracking skips checking the tracking cache. I know it doesn't add an entity to the cache when it reads a new one, but I would have assumed it would return a reference to a tracked instance if available, but it doesn't. This does mean to get the current data state for a detached entity you can't rely on `Reload`, but you can read again with `AsNoTracking`.

Comment: It worths noting that the topic starter wants to execute `ReloadAsync();` right after `.AsNoTracking()`. It doesn't make sense in any circumstances, even if `ReloadAsync();` would work. So, I just assume it was simplified example just for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

Just check below things.

1. whether you're doing `context.Update(` or `context.Entity.Update(` anywhere in the code. (this might cause such issues)
2. Make sure to not hold the DbContext instance for too long. By MS recommendation they should be either Transient or Scoped (and not singleton).

If you're doing `context.Update(` anywhere in the code and holding the DbContext instance for considerably long time, there will be high chances you're trying to update the same tracked entity multiple times in the DbContext lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

`ReloadAsync()` is not compatible with `AsNoTracking()` because it implies using tracked entity which is not the case if the `AsNoTracking()` was earlier applied.

If we need to refresh data from Db we can use `GetDatabaseValuesAsync()` instead. It works as `ReloadAsync()`but doesn't want to change entity tracker.